# How can I remove data from one column that exists in another column?

Tags: sql

I am having trouble trying to write a query.

I have one table that has multiple columns in it.

What I am trying to do is to basically trim one column that has the same data in another.

EXAMPLE:

```
column1 | Column2
123ABC  | 123
789DEF  | 789
```

So what i am trying to do is to take the value that is in column 2 and remove it from column 1 and just have column 1 just show like ABC, DEF.

Comment: Try `REPLACE(column1, column2, '')`

Comment: What [tag:RDBMS] are you using?

Comment: Have you looked at the string functions in your database's documentation?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server / MySQL

```
UPDATE tableName
SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, column2, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is dependent on the database server.  Basically, you want to update the table, setting column1 to be its current value with the value of column2 removed.  Here's how it could be done with MySQL:

```
update table
   set column1 = replace(column1, column2, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all your table can be truncated, you can do:

```
UPDATE Table SET column1 = SUBSTRING(column1, 3, LEN(column1))
```

OR

```
UPDATE Table SET column1 = SUBSTRING(column1, LEN(Column2), LEN(column1))
```

These commands are, for reference purpose, in MSSQL sintax.

Comment: I particularly don't recommend REPLACE, since you can have duplications on your string, example: "123123" or "AB123C" on column1.